# UITextView Alignment in RTL languages

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using Xcode 4.6.2 and targeting iOS 6 and above.
I have created sample code for my problem.

Code in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

- (IBAction)btnLeftAlignment:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnCenterAlignment:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnRightAlignment:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnJustifiedAlignment:(id)sender;


@end
```

Code in .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTextView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.myTextView.delegate = self;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnLeftAlignment:(id)sender
{
    myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}

- (IBAction)btnCenterAlignment:(id)sender
{
    myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}

- (IBAction)btnRightAlignment:(id)sender
{
    myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}

- (IBAction)btnJustifiedAlignment:(id)sender
{
    myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
}

@end
```

Interface Design

http://d.pr/i/oP7G

http://d.pr/i/1TM

The problem is this:

After adding some text to the TextView, if the keyboard is English the NSTextAlignment is working just fine. 
But if I change the keyboard to Arabic and write anything the NSTextAlignment will not respond, it will not change the alignment.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use textfield delegates

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

and set the alignment according to the text entered

The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character. Here you can replace your input with a new NSString where you put the characters from right to left.

also set

```
textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

to move your prompt on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Select UITextView then goto attribute inspector in alignment section select fourth (Equal) alignment